# Using pointer to C++ vectors in Cython

Tags: pointers, cython

I was trying define pointers to C++ vectors in Cython, and I noticed a strange behavior that I cannot explain with my Cython knowledge. Below, I have created a pointer to a vector of double based on `T` range. I either assign `a` to `a_low` or `a_high`.

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef vector[double] a_low = [1.0, 2e-03, -4e-07, 6.3e-10, -2.21e-5, -3.45e+01];
cdef vector[double] a_high = [-2.21e-01, 4.1e-03, -6.12e-02, 1.65e-09, -9.3e-6, -1.4e+02];

def h_calc(double T):
    cdef vector[double] *a
    cdef double h
    if (T<1000.0):
        a = &a_low;
    else:
        a = &a_high;
    print(a[0])
    h = 0.0;
    return h;
```

executing `h_calc(1200);` gives out `[-0.221, 0.0041, -0.0612, 1.65e-09, -9.3e-06, -140.0]` which results from `print(a[0])`. Here, because `T>1000`, we see `a_high` was displayed as output.

What I don't understand is why `a[0]` does not return the first value of the vector `a_high` , but rather the whole vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cython dereferencing (i.e. `*a` in c++) is spelled as `a[0]` as the former is not valid python syntax while the latter is - see the "Types" section [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html)

I.e. whats happening is:

- your `a` is of type `vector[double] *`,
- `a[0]` is the dereferenced version (i.e. just a `vector[double]`)
- `print(a[0])` converts `vector[double]` to a python list and prints that (i.e. the whole list)
- (this is also why `a[1]` crashes - it's effectively doing `*(a+1)`, and getting a memory violation)

---

Also for what it's worth the assignment from the python list should work - Cython effectively rewrites it to loop over the python list calling `push_back(...)` on each item for you.

Answer (score 1):

[] is a PyObject. You can't assign it to a c++ type (as evidenced with cdef) of a vector. The conversion isn't implicit. Likely the whole string of values is being treated as the first element. What happens when you access a[1]?

You have to declare the vector, and assign the values to it separately.

`cdef vector[double] a_low`

`a_low.push_back(1.0) a_low.push_back(2e-03) ...`

Perhaps you can also try experimenting with
`vector::insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);`, which can take an array of elements. Again, you would have to pass it a c array type, so you would have to declare and fill your array before passing it.

`cdef double array[6]`

`array[:] = [1.0, 2e-03, -4e-07, 6.3e-10, -2.21e-5, -3.45e+01]` then pass it to  vector::insert.

As you can see you can fill a C style array but not a vector in Cython in a one-liner. This raises the question, why not just use arrays in the first place?

Comment: Thanks
I understand your point about [] being a Python object and type converstions, but I don't understand why I can access items of a_low or a_high by indexing, but I cannot do that with the pointer, a.
BTW, when I try access a[1] in Python side, the program stops with no errors which based on my my experience means that a[1] is null or 1 is beyond the range of a.